# How do I enable timestamps in the Windows 10 firewall log?

Tags: logging, windows-10

I've activated firewall logs on my Windows 10 Pro version. Unfortunately, my logs show no timestamps.

How can I enable timestamps?

Answer (score 0):

Both the header and body (date — in the format YYYY-MM-DD and time — local time in the format HH:MM:SS /24) of log file contain timestamps by default.

Just make sure that when customizing the settings you enable "log successful connections".